# Two callbacks separated by double pipes?

Tags: javascript

Sorry for my possibly naive question, but I am totally novice to JavaScript.

I do not understand this:

```
return cordova.exec(success || onSuccess, fail || onFail, "Navigation", "exercise", [programId, levelId, orientation]);
```

The first two arguments are callbacks (success callback and failure callback),

but I do not understand: two callbacks separated by `||` like **`success || onSuccess`** ????

I am confused.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If `success` doesn't exist, use `onSuccess`. There's some major uglIness there.

Comment: Please use the search: [`[javascript] "||"`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%22%7C%7C%22)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `||` operand means "OR", that is, use the `success` callback if it exists, OR if it does not exist, use `onSuccess`.

Answer (score 1):

success and onSuccess denotes the callback function (same case as fail and onFail)

so in their code their would be something like:

> var success = function() {
>       //some stuff here }
>
> var onSuccess = function() {
>       //some stuff apart from success function }

So it is if success function is not their use onSuccess (a fallback function to go to)